How to map a list of elements to a list of positions of a matrix
I have an all zero matrix
zeromatrix= ConstantArray[0,{4,4}]

I have a list of non-zero positions and a list of non-zero values
nonzeropositions={{1,3},{2,2},{3,4},{4,1}}
nonzeroelements={{7},{8},{9},{10}}

I basically want to have the non-zero elements occupy the non-zero positions specified in the above code.
I have tried:
DeleteCases[Flatten[Table[MapAt[nonzeroelements[[i]],zeromatrix,nonzeropositions[[i]]],{i,1,4}],1],{0,0,0,0}]

However, this outputs the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & {7}[0] & 0\\
0 & {8}[0] & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & {9}[0] \\
{10}[0] & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$
Which isn't exactly what I want. I have tried playing around with ReplacePart as well with little success.

Perhaps,
nzp = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}};
nze = {7, 8, 9, 10};
a = SparseArray[Thread[nzp -> nze], {4, 4}] // MatrixForm



You don't even need Thread. SparseArray[nzp -> nze, {4, 4}] works just as well.

@SjoerdSmit sorry you are right: brain fade‍♂️

ReplacePart[zeromatrix, 
    Thread[nonzeropositions -> Flatten@nonzeroelements]]

 (* {
      {0, 0, 7, 0}, 
      {0, 8, 0, 0}, 
      {0, 0, 0, 9}, 
      {10, 0, 0, 0}
    } *)


Using SubsetMap:
SubsetMap[Flatten[nonzeroelements] &, zeromatrix, nonzeropositions] // TeXForm


$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 7 & 0 \\
 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 \\
 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

